# python2.7 name '__path__' is not defined

Tags: python, path

I try to use pkgutil but get the following error, who know the reason why **path** can't access? thanks.

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)

    *__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
NameError: name '__path__' is not defined*
```

Comment: Where are you using this code.. In which function and class? This information will be helpful for debugging the code.

Comment: This code is mostly only meaningful if placed in the `__init__.py` of a package.

Answer (score -1):

You can use above line of code in "__init__.py" file of a package demopkg1.
"__init__.py" file contains:

```
import pkgutil
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Now use another file test.py with below line of code:

```
import demopkg1
print ('demopkg1 file          :', demopkg1.__file__)
print ('demopkg1 path          :', demopkg1.__path__)
```

When you will execute the file test.py which include package "demopkg1" give below output:

```
demopkg1 file          : E:\Work\Python\demopkg1\__init__.py
demopkg1 path          : ['E:\\Work\\Python\\demopkg1']
```